# Callback not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<div class="expand">
    <span>▲</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".expand").click(function(){
    if ($(this).children().text()=="▼") {
        $(this).children().fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $(this).children().text("▲");
        }); // callback?
        $(this).children().fadeIn("fast"); //woks
    } else {
        $(this).children().fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $(this).children().text("▼");
        }); // callback?
        $(this).children().fadeIn("fast"); //works
    };
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".words, .readings").slideToggle("fast"); //works
});
```

I tried debugging it by putting `alert('')` in callback, but nothing popped up, so I guess I'm making some simple mistake here. Basically, ▼ should fade out and when it fades out (callback), it should turn into ▲, and then fade in, like that. Pretty standard we seen everywhere if you ask me. Or I'm doing this completely wrong?

I'd prefer corrections on my implementation than completely different solutions, although they're welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of the callback, `this` is already the element you want, so `$(this).children()` returns an empty object because that `<span>` does not have children. Remove the `.children()` from the callback:

```
$(this).children().fadeOut("fast",function(){
    $(this).text("▲");
});
```

Comment: Why's `this` actually a `span`? Is that how callback works or is there a deeper meaning?

Comment: Since you've already selected $(this).children on the fadeOut, 'this' is now the span in the child function. Otherwise you are looking for the child's child.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Jesse is correct; it's how jQuery works. http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#callback-function

Answer (score 3):

Inside the callback `$(this)` is already the `span` that you are looking for. So just use `$(this).text()`, as `$(this).children()` will fetch nothing as there are no child elements for the span and it will eventually point to the wrong target event if it has children.

Also place your `fadeIn()` inside the callback, if outside it will get executed before the callback executes.

```
   $(".expand").click(function () {
    if ($(this).children().text() == "▼") {
        $(this).children().fadeOut("fast", function () {
            $(this).text("▲").fadeIn("fast");
        }); // callback?

    } else {
        $(this).children().fadeOut("fast", function () {
            $(this).text("▼").fadeIn("fast");
        }); // callback?

    };
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".words, .readings").slideToggle("fast"); //works
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNnnk/)**

You can just simplify this to:

```
$(".expand").click(function () {
    $(this).children().fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).text(function (_, val) {
            return val == "▼" ? "▲" : "▼";
        }).fadeIn("fast");
    })

    $(this).parent().parent().find(".words, .readings").slideToggle("fast"); //works
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6V4d/)**

Comment: `fadeIn()` is working fine outside the callback. I'm not sure I understand how `this` points to `span` though.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović it will work find but it will fadin before the textchanges.. I mean you wont get that exact effect of text change.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Plus you can simplify your code. see my update.

Comment: It SHOULD fade in before the text changes. It fades out, the text changes while invisible and then it fades in with the new text. I'll look into your optimization - I'm still a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: Sure you are welcome. When you make a call back on a target that will be this context inside the callback. So here children function result

Comment: Also use find. it is faster than children. .find ('> span').